# C++ compiles on Windows but errors under OS X GCC

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, gcc

Following code compiles just fine under Visual Studio 2012 Express, Windows 8

But on my preferred platform, Eclipse Juno, GCC 4.2 on OS X 
I receive the following error:

../src/Test.cpp:20: error: 'std::istream& TestNS::operator>>(std::istream&, TestNS::Test&)' should have been declared inside 'TestNS'

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using std::istream;

namespace TestNS
{
class Test
{
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, Test &value);

public:
    Test(double real, double image);

private:
    double real;
    double image;
    void initialize(double real, double image);

};
}

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

using std::istream;
using namespace TestNS;

TestNS::Test::Test(double real = 0.0, double image = 0.0) : real(real), image(image)
{

}

void TestNS::Test::initialize(double real,  double image)
{
this->real = real;
this->image = image;
}

istream& TestNS::operator>> (istream &in, TestNS::Test &value)
{
value.real = 10.0;
value.image = 10.0;

return in;

}

int main()
{

}
```

Any assistance would be most helpful.
Working on assignment for school project.

Comment: TestNS is not the class, it is the namespace in the header file, professor indicates this is needed.

Comment: assignment indicates that must be friend function.

Comment: without TestNS:: function is global function not friend function,  Code compiles under Windows, Visual Studio, but not Eclipse GCC OS X

Comment: it DOES compile under OS X with GCC 4.2

Comment: I rebuilt an entirely new project and still does not work,  Paths and Symbols, include path is set to: /usr/include/c++/4.2.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that GCC is correct in giving the error.  In your example, the friend declaration of `operator>>` does specify that `operator>>` will be a member of `TestNS`, but it doesn't actually declare it there.  You still need a declaration of `operator>>` inside `TestNS` before you can define it outside of `TestNS`:

```
namespace TestNS
{
    class Test
    {
        friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, Test &value);

    public:
        Test(double real, double image);

    private:
        double real;
        double image;
        void initialize(double real, double image);

    };

    istream &operator>>(istream &in,Test &value); // need this
}
```

Now this is ok:

```
istream& TestNS::operator>> (istream &in, TestNS::Test &value)
{
    value.real = 10.0;
    value.image = 10.0;        
    return in;    
}
```

The relevant part of the standard is 7.3.1.2 p2 (for C++03):

> Members of a named namespace can also be defined outside that
>   namespace by explicit qualification of the name being defined,
>   **provided that the entity being defined was already declared in the namespace**...

The next paragraph indicates (although somewhat indirectly) that although the friend declaration inside the class does make the function a member of the namespace, it does not actually declare it there, since a separate declaration is necessary for the function's name to become visible within the namespace:

> If a `friend` declaration in a non-local class first declares a class
>   or function, the friend class or function is a member of the innermost
>   enclosing namespace.  The name of the friend function is not found by
>   simple name lookup **until a matching declaration is provided in that
>   namespace scope** (either before or after the class declaration granting
>   friendship).

Comment: Thanks Vaughn,  Awesome reference provided.